# Source Control & Domino Designer : can I ignore <noteinfo> and <modified> tags?

Tags: git, xpages

Is there anyway to tell git or Sourcetree 'listen, I don't really care if the content of these xml tags change'?

```
<noteinfo>
```

and

```
<modified>
```

seem to be prime candidates for this.

I'm aware of a .gitignore that ignores stuff at the file level, but at this level?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dora by Cameron Gregor attemps to handle exactly this. It's [available on OpenNTF](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Dora) and [on Github](https://github.com/camac/dora).

Comment: I've had problems in the past with applying it to an existing NSF. Some design elements like Database Script may have nothing in them, which caused problems for Dora (not sure if that's still an issue).

Comment: Hi Per, yes that's what I was looking for. I can see that he's using GIT attributes, so that looks promising. I would have thought this would be an inexpensive tweak of the eclipse <-> ods mechanism. As it is, it makes any kind of merging annoying.

Comment: Yes, the meta tags are annoying when it comes to source control

Comment: This project seems to be outdated, does it make sense to invest time? 
Are there alternatives to this [project](https://github.com/camac/dora)

Comment: @GeorgKastenhofer Swiper is the replacement: https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Swiper

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten Now I have tested this plugin, unfortunately it would only work in the right way, if you have [build automatically](https://github.com/camac/Swiper/issues/3) switched on. Furthermore I found another bug: Internal fields like $DesignerVersion and $$ScriptName get lost if you switch between branches!